# WebSocket connection to <url> failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, node-static

I' m new to WebSocket and Node.js. I'm trying to create a real-time chat as a basic program. I basically based my code [here](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/cloud/apaas/node-webSocket/nodecloud-websocket.html). I run my code in Amazon Linux for it to run as a real web server. I always got an error after I input the user's name.

I use node-static as a static server API for my index.html file.

Here's my code for my javascript: [app.js](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3pFYytlmtQAdXRXa0Nqa2dBYmM/view?usp=sharing)
And here's my code for index.html located inside the "public" folder: [index.html](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3pFYytlmtQATjFmdVNGNkZPbzQ/view?usp=sharing)
I always get the error at line15 in index.html.

Can anyone tell me what is the problem there? I tried moving that part anywhere inside the connectToChat() function but the error is still there.

Comment: Can you share the error? you will find it in console of your browser.

Comment: WebSocket connection to 'ws://<mywebserver>:8000/index.html' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Comment: You have an error in url change your websocket is on `ws://<mywebserver>:8000` without index.html in end.

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in url you call. 
It have to be `ws://<mywebserver>:8000`
instead of `ws://<mywebserver>:8000/index.html`

To fix it, in **index.html** , change this line

`var url = document.URL.replace("http://", "ws://");`
to

`var url = document.origin.replace("http://", "ws://");`

Comment: I tried your suggestion. The error is still the same, but now without the "/index.html".

Comment: Ok. Can you check if port 8000 is open for income connections?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I was able to fix it by pointing the client script to the real IP. It is not the best solution, but it will do for the moment.

```
let socket = io('http://000.000.000.000:0000');
```

Hope it helps!